# monitoring when a process starts using too much memory

Tags: debian, monitoring, memory, oom

I have a Debian server where some processes going rogue from time to time and start consuming too much memory. How I could monitor this at process level so I can set an alarm? Currently I monitor when the server starts using too much memory but I would like to monitor the process individually.

Comment: What monitoring system are you using?

Comment: I am using zabbix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I monitor the total RAM used by apache:

```
ps -e -orss=,args= | awk '/apache/{ SUM += $1} END { print SUM }'
```

Just change `apache` to your process.

Comment: is that the RAM used currently or the RAM that has been used while the process has been runnning? Thanks!

Comment: Currently used.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/)

Comment: I do not see how monit solves my problem.

Comment: Monit solve it easily : http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#resource_testing
Here example how I monitor memory of my tomcat processes and if something get wrong send an alarm and run set of scripts that take number of snapshot of running services before restart service:
 
check process tomcat6 with pidfile /var/run/tomcat6.pid
    if cpu > 80% for 5 cycles then alert
    if totalmem > 7 GB for 2 cycles then alert else if succeeded for 5 cycles then alert
    if totalmem > 7 GB for 2 cycles then exec "/usr/local/bin/asset4/jvm_mon.sh"

Comment: Thanks! I did not know it and it looks interesting.

Comment: +1 for monit. As Ruslan explained, it can not only alert on the failure mode, but it can be given instructions on how to remedy the problem (which is normally a case of restarting the service)

Answer (score 1):

Use Nagios and it's "check_procs" plugin with the RSS-metric parameter:

```
 -r, --rss=RSS
  Only scan for processes with RSS higher than indicated.
```

E.g.:

```
"check_procs -w 1500000 -c 2000000 --metric=RSS"
```

Alter w & c to fit your warning- and critical-levels for the misbehaving process.

To see the current RSS use this one-liner and check the proc its RSS in the third column:

```
ps -eo pid,ppid,rss,size,vsize,sz,pmem,comm
```